# All from table A and include a row for each of a set from table B even if there is no related record in Table B

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I had a hard job describing this simple problem...

I want to return a series of data points for a stacked bar chart for each stack Label and Bar, whether or not there is a record for the Label/Bar datapoint, a null value being returned where there is no data record.  The 'missing' Label must also be included:

```
    Label   Bar  Value
    a       X    99
    a       Y    23
    a       Z    97
    b       X    null
    b       Y    32
    b       Z    null
```

I have table DataLabel that contains the Labels for the each type of datapoint in the bar stack and a table DataSeries that contains the X-axis Labels and the Y-axis values to be calculated for each datapoint.

```
    create table DataLabel
    (id number
    , label varchar2(10));

    Insert into DataLabel values (1, 'a');
    Insert into DataLabel values (2, 'b');

    Create table DataSeries
    (id number
    , DataLabel_id number
    , val number
    , DataSeriesName varchar2(5));

    Insert into DataSeries values (1, 1, 99, 'X');
    Insert into DataSeries values (11, 1, 23, 'Y');
    Insert into DataSeries values (12, 2, 32, 'Y');
    Insert into DataSeries values (21, 1, 97, 'Z');
```

The problem arises, where the DataSeries table be does not contain a corresponding value for a DataLabel for a given datapoint.

I have managed an inelegant solution that does return the desired result in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a780a/2) using a Union join, but is there a better solution....?

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to  bring in the values:

```
select dl.label, dsn.dataseriesname,
       ds.val
from datalabel dl cross join
     (select distinct dataseriesname from dataseries
     ) dsn left join
     dataseries ds
     on ds.datalabel_id = dl.id and
        ds.dataseriesname = dsn.dataseriesname
order by dl.label, dsn.dataseriesname;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a780a/6) is the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

A `cross join` among tables containing a correlated subquery might be an option :

```
select distinct label, DataSeriesName as bar,
      (select val 
         from DataSeries 
        where DataSeriesName=s.DataSeriesName 
          and DataLabel_id=l.id) as value
  from DataSeries s
 cross join DataLabel l 
 order by label, bar
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0f60c5fe75dada184a89d4fd9ec05bf7)</kbd>